# Adding space *just* on right size of x-axis, color based on relative position, specify labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, colorbrewer

I have a time series graph of 49 countries, and I'd like to do three things: (1) prevent the country label name from being cut off, (2) specify so that the coloring is based on the position in the graph rather than alphabetically, and (3) specify which countries I would like to label (49 labels in one graph is too many).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
library(zoo)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(viridis)

colourCount = length(unique(df$newCol))
getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "Paired"))

## Yearly Incorporation Rates
ggplot(df,aes(x=year2, y=total_count_th, group = newCol, color = newCol)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_dl(aes(label = newCol), 
          method= list(dl.trans(x = x + 0.1), 
          "last.points", cex = 0.8)) +
          scale_color_manual(values = getPalette(colourCount)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1),
          legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = "Title",
           x = "Year",
           y = "Count")
```

This code works -- there are 49 lines, and each of them is labelled. But it just so happens that all the countries with the highest y-values have the same/similar colors (red/orange). So is there a way to specify the colors dynamically (maybe with scale_color_identity)? And how do I add space *just* on the right side of the labels? I found the expand = expand_scale, but it added space on both sides (though I did read that in the new version, it should be possible to do so.)

I am also fine defining a list of 49 manually-defined colors rather than using the color ramp.

Comment: Can you add some fake example data so we can try things out for you?

Comment: Sure! Is there a preferred way to create datasamples? (e.g. in Stata there is -dataex-)

Comment: 1) try displaying the country name using `str_wrap(name, #of_chars_per_line)`, and/or using `coordinate_cartesian(clip = "off")` to show text beyond plot range.

Comment: The easiest is to include the output that is produced when you run `dput(df)` or if that's unnecessarily long, `dput(head(df, #_rows))` in the body of your question. More tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: 2) one approach could be to pre-calculate some assignment of colors, like `mutate(color_assigned = case_when(SOME_CONDITIONS ~ COLORS))` and then use `scale_color_identity`.

Comment: 3) similarly, you might create a display_name variable that is set to "" for the countries you don't want to label.

Comment: Hi @JonSpring Thank you for your help! Your solution for the ```coordinate_cartesian``` got me on the right track. I fixed it by specifying ```coord_cartesian(xlim_c(1,44), expand = TRUE)```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to limit the x axis by adding something like

```
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1,44), expand = TRUE)
```

In this case, I had 41 years of observations on the axis, so by specifying 44, I added space to the x-axis.
Thank you to @JonSpring for the help and getting me to the right answer!